# Spark 1.4.1 and Scala: create DataFrame from scratch

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created a bunch of case classes that I need for testing purposes. I'm then doing a lot of these statements:

```
case class Bar(id: Int, desc: String)
val foo = Bar(1, "baz")
val bar = sc.makeRDD(Array(foo)).toDF
```

That works. Because I'm doing many of these calls I thought it'd be nice to create a function:

```
def dfify[T: ClassTag](obj: T): DataFrame = sc.makeRDD(Array(obj)).toDF
```

However, that gives me the following error:

```
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]
```

I've tried adding the context bound T <: Product as suggested [here](http://answers.candoerz.com/question/72662/spark-rdd-to-dataframe-conversion.aspx) in a slightly different context, but that does not help.

The problem is that without the function it works, but it would be nice to have some of the repetitive bits somewhat simplified. Something that I thought would take be 1 minute has taken quite a bit more with no result.

I'm on Spark 1.4.1 and I cannot change that, so `createDataFrame()` is not available to me.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to create an `SQLContext` and import its implicits, otherwise the implicit conversion of an `RDD` into a `DataFrameHolder` (which has the `toDF` method) isn't in scope.

Another issue is - `ClassTag` isn't enough, a `TypeTag` is required too.

This code compiles and works:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

def dfify[T <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag](obj: T): DataFrame = sc.makeRDD(Array(obj)).toDF()
```